SwiftUI NavigationStack - Pass binding along with normal data from a child view to a third view
I’m struggling for a long time with navigation in SwiftUI, after having some bugs when using NavigationLink I’m trying to do it the latest way and solve this problem once and for all. This is the minimal example and the best I could do so far and I'm sure this question will be useful for others:
import SwiftUI

struct FoodModel: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}

struct DataForEditFoodsView: Hashable {

    var userid: Int
    var foods: [FoodModel]
}

struct NavStack: View {
   
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                Text("create")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        path.append("create")
                    }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: DataForEditFoodsView.self){ selection in
                EditFoodsView(userid: selection.userid, foods: selection.$foods)
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: String.self){ selection in
                if(selection == "create"){
                    CreateFoodsView(path: $path)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CreateFoodsView: View {
    
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    
    @State var foods: [FoodModel] = [FoodModel]()
    @State var foodsCreated = false
    
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Text("edit foods")
                .padding(.bottom, 30)
                .onTapGesture {
                    path.append(DataForEditFoodsView(userid: 123, foods: self.foods))
                }
            
            ForEach($foods, id: \.id){ food in
                Text(food.name.wrappedValue)
            }
        }
        .task{
            if(!foodsCreated){
                foodsCreated = true
                
                foods.append(FoodModel(id: 1 ,name: "pizza"))
                foods.append(FoodModel(id: 2 ,name: "sushi"))
                foods.append(FoodModel(id: 3 ,name: "salad"))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct EditFoodsView: View {
    
    var userid: Int
    @Binding var foods: [FoodModel]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Text("bla")
        }
        .task{
            foods.remove(at: 0)
        }
    }
}

I get 2 errors:
Type 'DataForEditFoodsView' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'

for struct DataForEditFoodsView
and
struct DataForEditFoodsView

for selection.$foods
and when I use the suggested "fixes" or try other things then all kind of other errors appear.
The answers in How to pass binding to child view in the new NavigationStack.navigationDestination aren't helping since the data doesn't get passed from a child view to a third view, or I just don't get how to use the answers.
Please no questions like „why don’t u edit the foods directly in CreateFoodsView“ or „why don’t u initialise [FoodsModel] in NavStack and pass it from there to other views“. I need exactly what Im asking for, one of the reasons is easy to explain is: In the final app, there will be the possibility to have multiple instances of CreateFoodsView and EditFoodsView, so with different [FoodsModel] that needs to be passed to EditFoodsView

pls include details about how you implemented the Equatable and  "then all kind of other errors appear." in your question.  You should not use more than one navigation stack for your navigation purposes especially when you pass path binding back to parent view.

I don't know what Equatable is and how to use it. When I click on the fix then static func == (lhs: DataForEditFoodsView, rhs: DataForEditFoodsView) -> Bool { <#code#> } appears and I don't know what this is. Man I already knew I will get comments like yours. Look, I don't program apps for a company but this is my own app. And because of that, I don't need to learn swift/swiftui 100%, otherwise I wouldn't need stackoverflow. Everything I do I will do only once so please just show the solution.

Oh and where do you see two NavigationStacks??

one in nav stack and one in create foods view. you only need one on parent view

Oh this was a mistake when I copied a view to edit it, thanks. Please revert your downvote, I gave all the details and I'm sure they are enough to understand what is needed!

State should always be private

NavigationDestination with the type is not compatible with Binding you have to use the isPresented version. There are a ton of workarounds but none of them will be stable in all versions of SwiftUI

Ok thanks... :(
